# Trouble creating/manipulating Pandas DataFrame from given list of JSON records

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have json records in the file json_data. I used `pd.DataFrame(json_data)` to make a new table, `pd_json_data`, using these records.

[pandas table pd_json_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuoYq.png)

I want to manipulate `pd_json_data` to return a new table with primary key *(url,hour)*, and then a column *updated* that contains a boolean value.

*hour* is based on the *number of checks*. For example, if *number of checks* contains 378 at row 0, the new table should have the numbers 1 through 378 in *hour*, with True in *updated* if the number in *hour* is a number in *positive checks*.

Any ideas for how I should approach this?

Comment: Help clarify: Do you want a list in your dataframe cell from 1 to n, where `n` is the integer in the `number of checks` column? And then just a boolean if `number of checks` is in `positive checks`?

Answer (score 0):

#### Updated Answer

Make fake data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'number of checks': [5, 10, 300, 8], 
                   'positive checks':[[1,3,10], [10,11], [9,200], [1,8,7]], 
                   'url': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']})
```

Output

```
   number of checks positive checks url
0                 5      [1, 3, 10]   a
1                10        [10, 11]   b
2               300        [9, 200]   c
3                 8       [1, 8, 7]   d
```

Iterate and create new dataframes, then concatenate

```
dfs = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    hour =  np.arange(1, row['number of checks'] + 1)
    df_cur = pd.DataFrame({'hour' : hour,
                          'url': row['url'],
                          'updated': np.in1d(hour, row['positive checks'])})
    dfs.append(df_cur)
df_final = pd.concat(dfs)

    hour updated url
0       1    True   a
1       2   False   a
2       3    True   a
3       4   False   a
4       5   False   a
0       1   False   b
1       2   False   b
2       3   False   b
3       4   False   b
4       5   False   b
5       6   False   b
6       7   False   b
7       8   False   b
8       9   False   b
9      10    True   b
0       1   False   c
1       2   False   c
```

#### Old answer

Now build new dataframe

```
df1 = df[['url']].copy()
df1['hour'] = df['number of checks'].map(lambda x: list(range(1, x + 1)))
df1['updated'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['number of checks'] in x['positive checks'], axis=1)
```

Output

```
  url                                            hour updated
0   a                                 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]   False
1   b                 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]    True
2   c  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...   False
3   d                        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]    True
```

Comment: This is close to what I am looking for. I guess the only change would be to have the rows in *hour* not contain a list of numbers, but rather for each row of *hour* to contain an int. So in the first row of the new dataframe, *hour* would be 1 with *updated* True because 1 is in *positive checks*. In the second row of the new dataframe, *hour* would be 2 with *updated* False because 2 is not in *positive checks*.

Comment: In your example the new table will have a total number of 5 + 10 + 300 + 8 = 323 rows.